# ASP.NET Core 8 Web API : suppress the browser's authentication dialog with no access to IIS

Tags: c#, authentication, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-8.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API deployed on a server where I don't have access to IIS.

When working in local, if the user is not authenticated, it will directly return a http 401 error.

However, in the deployed version, if any service returns a 401 or uses the `[Authorize]` (and the user is not authenticated), it will generate the browser's authentication dialog, which I don't want.

I've already contacted the company that I use for the hosting, but I've been told that they can't modify the IIS configuration since it affects multiple clients.

My idea to avoid this is for the services that return a 401, change it to a 403 (or similar).

My issue is with the services that use `[Authorize]`, here is an example of a very simple function that will return a 401 if a JWT is not provided or the JWT is not valid (has been tampered with for example):

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet("[action]")]
[SwaggerOperation("Check JWT validity.",
    "This API function will check if the provided JWT is valid.")]
[SwaggerResponse(StatusCodes.Status200OK, "Returned if everything went OK.", typeof(string))]
[SwaggerResponse(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized, "Returned if the user has not been authetificated.")]
public IActionResult checkToken() 
{
    return Ok();
}
```

I've seen on-line that you can modify how `[Authorize]` works, but I was unable to make it work, it still returned a 401 instead of a 403, for example I tried this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using System.Linq;

public class CustomAuthorizeFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        // Is user authenticated
        if (!context.HttpContext.User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated == true)
        {
            context.Result = new StatusCodeResult(403);
            return;
        }

        // Check roles if needed
        var authorizeAttributes = context.ActionDescriptor.EndpointMetadata
            .OfType<AuthorizeAttribute>()
            .ToList();

        if (authorizeAttributes.Any(attr => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(attr.Roles) && !context.HttpContext.User.IsInRole(attr.Roles)))
        {
            context.Result = new StatusCodeResult(403);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

And in `program.cs` I registered it:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new CustomAuthorizeFilter());
});
```

As additional information, in program.cs, this is the Authentication I've added:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options => {
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(
        options => {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0),
                ValidIssuers = new List<string>{
                    "https://www.myweb.com/"
                },
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value!))
            };
        }
    );
```

Also, my only method is to change the response from 401 to 403, becasue the server is adding www-authenticate: Basic realm="win.host" instead of www-authenticate: bearer.
How could I achieve to make authorize return a 403 instead of 401 so that no browser's authentication dialog is shown?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A user can be **authenticated** (not "authentificated".....)

Comment: @marc_s thanks for fixing it. Do you know a possible solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code by using the  `CustomAuthorizeFilter` for changing the status code to 403 is correct. now  in your `AddJwtBearer` method, you can configure JwtBearer authentication events to customize the behavior when authentication fails. Specifically, in the authentication failed event, you can modify the response to return a 403 status code instead of the default 401.

Here is the code you could try:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options => {
    // ... 
}).AddJwtBearer(options => {
    // ... 
    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnChallenge = context =>
        {
            if (context.AuthenticateFailure != null)
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                context.HandleResponse(); 

                var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { error = "Forbidden" });
                return context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});
```